# Jsonp with MooTools

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mootools

I'm learning javascript and now I'm trying to work with mootools. 
I would like to work with json files in remote so I'm trying to use jsonp. Right now I have a textbox and when I click a button I would like to make a request of a json file. The url of the json file is something like www.mysite.com/json/sometext where sometext is the content of the textbox. The problem is that I don't really understand how the request and mootools work.

Right now I don't have the code because I don't know how to start (I'm a beginner) but I would like to get the json file at http://m.airpim.com/json/public/search?q=daniele&k=&e=1 if in the textbox I wrote "daniele" and I would like to save the json in an array.

How can I do it?

Comment: this is not JSONP. it's JSON. JSONP is a wrapper around JSON that puts a function around the JSON response so js can read it. eg http://m.airpim.com/json/public/search?q=daniele&k=&e=1&callback=foo should wrap this in `foo({ ... })` and that would mean you can use Request.JSONP. else, you need a proxy due to same origin XSS restrictions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jsonp request with MooTools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257872/jsonp-request-with-mootools)