# Jsonp request with MooTools

Tags: javascript, json, mootools, jsonp

I'm studying javascript and right now I'm working with some json files and mootools. The problem is that I would like to work with json on other domains so I'm trying to use Jsonp. I'm trying to write some lines of code but I can't really understand what I'm doing because I'm not a really programmer (usually I write few lines of code in C# without working with json, xml or any kind of data).

That's my code:

```
function getSearchValue()
{
var searchvalue = getElementById('campo').value;
var firstparturl = "http://m.airpim.com/json/public/search?";
var lastparturl = "&k=&e=1";
var finalurl = firstparturl + searchvalue + lastparturl;
return finalurl;
}

var myRequest = new Request.JSONP
(
{url: getSearchValue(),
 onComplete: function(data) 
    {

        // Here I should save the json data in one array

    }
}).send();
```

The data that I receive are a json object? If yes how can I save it into an array ... I mean what's the mootools syntax for parsing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jsonp with MooTools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246683/jsonp-with-mootools). Like I commented in your other question - you cannot use JSONP with a vanilla JSON service that does not support it - unless you create a local proxy that fetches or can enable CORS on the remote. and even so, you'd use Request.JSON

Comment: so I have to use a proxy like YQL?

Comment: yes or you make a small php/whatever file that does a curl request to the url and then returns the response locally, I tend to do that for services that lack JSONP support. long-term reliance on anything YAHOO is probably naive and should not be used for anything but research imo.

Comment: see https://gist.github.com/3017516 for a pseudo example. don't use in production w/o validation and security review

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)